# How to make divider blink in js clock

Tags: javascript

I got nice js clock, but I don't know how to make divider between hrs and minutes blink. Here's how it looks like http://www.ricocheting.com/code/javascript/html-generator/digital-clock and here's the code

```js
<div>
<img src="dg8.gif" name="hr1"><img 
src="dg8.gif" name="hr2"><img 
src="dgc.gif"><img 
src="dg8.gif" name="mn1"><img 
src="dg8.gif" name="mn2"><img 
src="dgc.gif"><img 
src="dg8.gif" name="se1"><img 
src="dg8.gif" name="se2"><img 
src="dgam.gif" name="ampm"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// (c) 2000-2014 ricocheting.com
dg = new Array();
dg[0]=new Image();dg[0].src="dg0.gif";
dg[1]=new Image();dg[1].src="dg1.gif";
dg[2]=new Image();dg[2].src="dg2.gif";
dg[3]=new Image();dg[3].src="dg3.gif";
dg[4]=new Image();dg[4].src="dg4.gif";
dg[5]=new Image();dg[5].src="dg5.gif";
dg[6]=new Image();dg[6].src="dg6.gif";
dg[7]=new Image();dg[7].src="dg7.gif";
dg[8]=new Image();dg[8].src="dg8.gif";
dg[9]=new Image();dg[9].src="dg9.gif";
dgam=new Image();dgam.src="dgam.gif";
dgpm=new Image();dgpm.src="dgpm.gif";

function dotime(){ 
    var d=new Date();
    var hr=d.getHours(),mn=d.getMinutes(),se=d.getSeconds();

    // set AM or PM
    document.ampm.src=((hr<12)?dgam.src:dgpm.src);

    // adjust from 24hr clock
    if(hr==0){hr=12;}
    else if(hr>12){hr-=12;}

    document.hr1.src = getSrc(hr,10);
    document.hr2.src = getSrc(hr,1);
    document.mn1.src = getSrc(mn,10);
    document.mn2.src = getSrc(mn,1);
    document.se1.src = getSrc(se,10);
    document.se2.src = getSrc(se,1);
}

function getSrc(digit,index){
    return dg[(Math.floor(digit/index)%10)].src;
}

window.onload=function(){
    dotime();
    setInterval(dotime,1000);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK I solved it by making simply animated divider gif as per script's writer suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly which DOM object you want to blink, but conceptually, you can just alternate a DOM object between the CSS style of `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible`.  Since you're already updating the time each second, you can toggle the visibility state each time you update the time.

Changing the visibility state just makes the colon invisible, but it still takes up the same amount of space in the page layout (which have the effect of making it appear to blink).  You can read about the visibility style property [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility).

Using this code, just change this:

```
<img src="dgc.gif">
```

to this:

```
<img class="separator" src="dgc.gif">
```

For each colon that you want to blink.

```
// initialize visibility state
var vToggle = true;

function dotime(){ 
    var d=new Date();
    var hr=d.getHours(),mn=d.getMinutes(),se=d.getSeconds();

    // set AM or PM
    document.ampm.src=((hr<12)?dgam.src:dgpm.src);

    // adjust from 24hr clock
    if(hr==0){hr=12;}
    else if(hr>12){hr-=12;}

    document.hr1.src = getSrc(hr,10);
    document.hr2.src = getSrc(hr,1);
    document.mn1.src = getSrc(mn,10);
    document.mn2.src = getSrc(mn,1);
    document.se1.src = getSrc(se,10);
    document.se2.src = getSrc(se,1);

    // now toggle the visibility of the separator
    vToggle = !vToggle;
    var vis = vToggle ? "visibile" : "hidden";
    console.log(vis);
    var items = document.querySelectorAll(".separator");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].style.visibility = vis;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's "dgc" in this script, the divider in clock like so 01[ : ]20 to  01[  ]21 I don't want to hide it, I want to replace [ : ] with blank rectangle and then back to [ : ] again.

Comment: @user123 - please read what I've added to my question.  You don't have to replace with a blank rectangle.  Toggle the visibility will just make it invisible while still taking up the exact same amount of space which is perfect for a blinking style.

Comment: Yes but it will look ugly on my page as I use much bigger pics and it looks like digital clock, in real clock segment doesn't dissapear ;)

Comment: @user123 - then please describe what you want it to look like.  You asked for it to blink.  How does something blink if it doesn't disappear and the reappear on a regular interval?  As your question stands now, it apparently does not define exactly what you want well enough for anyone to provide an answer.  Please describe your specification for "blink".

Comment: @user123 - here's another guess at what you want for blink.  See if you like this working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9Logkhv1/.  If not, the structure is all there and you can tweak the timing to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick sketch using the black background span replacements for the black images you should be using:

```js
dg = new Array();
var pref = 'http://www.ricocheting.com/static/code/javascript/digital-clock/';
dg[0] = new Image();
dg[0].src = pref + "dg0.gif";
dg[1] = new Image();
dg[1].src = pref + "dg1.gif";
dg[2] = new Image();
dg[2].src = pref + "dg2.gif";
dg[3] = new Image();
dg[3].src = pref + "dg3.gif";
dg[4] = new Image();
dg[4].src = pref + "dg4.gif";
dg[5] = new Image();
dg[5].src = pref + "dg5.gif";
dg[6] = new Image();
dg[6].src = pref + "dg6.gif";
dg[7] = new Image();
dg[7].src = pref + "dg7.gif";
dg[8] = new Image();
dg[8].src = pref + "dg8.gif";
dg[9] = new Image();
dg[9].src = pref + "dg9.gif";
dgam = new Image();
dgam.src = pref + "dgam.gif";
dgpm = new Image();
dgpm.src = pref + "dgpm.gif";

function dotime() {
  var d = new Date();
  var hr = d.getHours(),
    mn = d.getMinutes(),
    se = d.getSeconds();

  // set AM or PM
  document.ampm.src = ((hr < 12) ? dgam.src : dgpm.src);

  // adjust from 24hr clock
  if (hr == 0) {
    hr = 12;
  } else if (hr > 12) {
    hr -= 12;
  }

  document.hr1.src = getSrc(hr, 10);
  document.hr2.src = getSrc(hr, 1);
  document.mn1.src = getSrc(mn, 10);
  document.mn2.src = getSrc(mn, 1);
  document.se1.src = getSrc(se, 10);
  document.se2.src = getSrc(se, 1);
  
  blink();
}

function getSrc(digit, index) {
  return dg[(Math.floor(digit / index) % 10)].src;
}

function blink() {
  if (document.querySelectorAll('.b')[0].style.visibility != 'visible') {
    document.querySelectorAll('.b')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.querySelectorAll('.b')[1].style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll('.b')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.querySelectorAll('.b')[1].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  dotime();  
  setInterval(dotime, 1000);
}
```

```css
.bh {background: black; width: 8px; height: 24px; position: absolute;z-index:-1}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://www.ricocheting.com/static/code/javascript/digital-clock/dg8.gif" name="hr1"><img 
    src="http://www.ricocheting.com/static/code/javascript/digital-clock/dg8.gif" name="hr2"><span class="bh"></span><img 
    src="http://www.ricocheting.com/static/code/javascript/digital-clock/dgc.gif" class="b"><img 
    src="http://www.ricocheting.com/static/code/javascript/digital-clock/dg8.gif" name="mn1"><img 
    src="http://www.ricocheting.com/static/code/javascript/digital-clock/dg8.gif" name="mn2"><span class="bh"></span><img 
    src="http://www.ricocheting.com/static/code/javascript/digital-clock/dgc.gif" class="b"><img 
    src="http://www.ricocheting.com/static/code/javascript/digital-clock/dg8.gif" name="se1"><img 
    src="http://www.ricocheting.com/static/code/javascript/digital-clock/dg8.gif" name="se2"><img 
    src="http://www.ricocheting.com/static/code/javascript/digital-clock/dgam.gif" name="ampm"></div>
```

---

So, in your final version, you'd toggle the `.b` src attributes between off and on states in the `blink` function. I couldn't find a blank image, so I put those `.bh` spans behind the images, but you get the idea.

Comment: It works with span but when I replace it with pic it doesn't.

Comment: I've replaced your span with `<img src="dgb.gif" class="bh">` `"dgb.gif"` is the blank, but then divider blinks and the blank is not appearing.

Comment: Does that image exist, is the path correct? I replaced my span with a random digit image and it worked.